# A Problem with Mdframed

Tags: tikz-styles, mdframed

I just copied a style from the `mdframed` Documentation.

[image: p4]
[image: p5]

I cannot find what is wrong with me as "pt" appears above the Theo.

1. I did modify the color blue to gray.
2. I use Xetex to compile for my unicode tex.
3. I have tried putting both in preamble and after.
4. I altered `\frametitleaboveskip`-> -15pt [ as the original one didnt work out for me]

   ```
   \documentclass[showframe,10pt,a5paper]{article}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage{amsmath}
   \usepackage{amsfonts}
   \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}


   \begin{document}
     \newcounter{theo}
       \newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
   \stepcounter{theo}%
   \ifstrempty{#1}%
   {\mdfsetup{%
           frametitle={%
               \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0]\node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray]
               { Theorem~\thetheo};}}
   }%
   {\mdfsetup{%
           frametitle={%
               \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0]
               \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray]
               { Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
   }%
   \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=7pt,linecolor=gray!20,linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
       frametitleaboveskip=-15pt\relax,}
   \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
   }{\end{mdframed}}


    %Where I start.

   \begin{theo}
    hi\end{theo}
    \end{document}
   ```

[image: pt above it!!!]

I cant understand why "pt" is there. Where should I omit it?

Thanks!

Comment: The optional argument `#1` is not used other than for the `\ifstrempty` test?

Comment: Additionally: You're using `xelatex`, but the document says `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` -- that does not match, actually

Comment: @ChristianHupfer You are right. I removed it n still it works. Never noticed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `frametitleaboveskip=-15pt\relax` this way isn't recognized as dimension value any longer, i.e. `-15pt` but breaks apart into `-15` and `pt`, which is left in the input then.

Also `\stepcounter` should be `\refstepcounter` rather to enable cross-referencing.

`showframe` isn't used here therefore I removed it.

I also suggest to define the new environment before `\begin{document}...`

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[framemethod=tikz]{mdframed}


\newcounter{theo}
\newenvironment{theo}[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{theo}%
  \ifstrempty{#1}%
  {\mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray]
        { Theorem~\thetheo};}}
  }%
  {\mdfsetup{%
      frametitle={%
        \tikz[baseline=(current bounding box.east),outer sep=0]
        \node[anchor=east,rectangle,fill=gray]
        { Theorem~\thetheo:~#1};}}%
  }%
  \mdfsetup{innertopmargin=7pt,linecolor=gray!20,linewidth=2pt,topline=true,
    frametitleaboveskip=-15pt}
  \begin{mdframed}[]\relax%
  }{%
\end{mdframed}%
}


% Where I start.

\begin{document}
\begin{theo}
  hi
\end{theo}
\end{document}
```

[image]